# RecylcerView Showing all items of array at first but after that it shows only first item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am displaying content of an array but it only shows all items whenever I change something in code after that it shows only first item of arrray.
I am using API level 24 and build tool version 24

```
public class AccountAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AccountAdapter.AccountHolder> {


    ArrayList<String> accountDetail;


    public AccountAdapter(ArrayList<String> accountDetail, Context context){
        this.accountDetail=accountDetail;          

    }

        @Override
        public AccountAdapter.AccountHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.account_row,parent,false);
        AccountHolder accountHolder=new AccountHolder(view);

        return accountHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AccountAdapter.AccountHolder holder, int position) {
    final String details = accountDetail.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(accountDetail.get(position).toString());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    return accountDetail.size();
    }

    public class AccountHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        protected TextView textView;
        public AccountHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.account_tv_row);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
this is how i'm calling adapter

```
        stringList= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.account));   
        account=new ArrayList<>(stringList);     
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_account_rv);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter=new AccountAdapter(account,getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this adapter. Error must be in other parts of code

Comment: @rsella can you confirm if calling adapter method is correct or not

Comment: That's the standard (and best) way to do that. Post the code that, when called, make RecyclerView items disappear

Comment: I got it, it was due to row layout
row layout height was set to match_parent